# Will a failing CMOS battery prevent my laptop from booting (90% of time)?

Tags: laptop, gateway, cmos

My old Gateway P-170L laptop (circa 2005) fails to boot 90+% of the time.  It will usually freeze up at the initial Windows logo screen.  After numerous restarts it may completely boot and continue to run normally.  At this point I can often do a complete shutdown and it will start fine, but more often it is the same issue.  I have replaced the battery and AC power adapter but that has made no difference.  The clock is usually fine (though it is occasionally off by as much as 3 or 4 hours, but only recently).  I have been booting with the wireless off so the clock should not reset anyway.

When it does run everything seems to work fine.  I am running Windows 10 Home, 32 bit system, no peripherals except for a wireless mouse.  Does this sound like a CMOS battery issue or should I be focusing elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely (but not impossible) that this is a BIOS issue - normally these would manifest prior to Windows starting to boot.

It's a guess on my part, but it sounds to me like it could be a failing PSU (specifically capacitors not able to provide enough peak power during startup).  It could also be a failing disk.